# ListView from an array received as string from a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have a main activity that has a `Recyclerview`, It displays a list image and a text as the title.

In the main activity I have three array lists; one for the image, one for its title and the last one "array" for a String array.

I am passing the `R.array.id` as a string into the next activity On Click of an item in the `MainActivity`. I send the image, title, and the `array`.

In the second `Activity`, where I check for incoming intent, Assign them to strings.

```
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");
String array= getIntent().getStringExtra("array_id");
```

Then I have called `setArray(array)` and then inside the function, I got stuck.

```
private void setArray(String array) {
    // Stuck here 
}
```

I don't know what to do. I have set a `ListView` in the second layout
and found this code on this site.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.extView);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.id, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

Which works, if I have a set the source to a static array id but how do I set it the string I receive?

Tried `getString(array)`, which did not work. I also need to set an `onClick` listener to the items.

Comment: What does your `setArray` function do? Please post the code from your `setArray` function.

Comment: @ReazMurshed at the moment, nothing.

Comment: @ReazMurshed , thats where I am stuck,.I put the listview code posted at the bottom, but dont know how i can use the text I get as "array" to work instead of R.array.id

Comment: my whole approach could be wrong too,

Comment: You need to have a custom adapter for your `ListView`. Please check my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying an array in a `ListView`, you need to have a custom adapter. The `ArrayAdapter` that you are currently using, is the native adapter for showing a list provided by Android SDK. However, you need a custom class if you need to show the `ListView` which populates the items dynamically from your array.

In order to do that, you need to have a custom adapter class like the following.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int resourceLayout;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resourceLayout = resource;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        }

        String p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
            tt1.setText(p.getId());
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Now you need a layout which indicates each item of your list. For example, the name of your layout is `list_item.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:height="40sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your second `Activity`, you need to initialize the adapter and set the adapter in your `ListView` like the following. Please note that, as the adapter takes a `List`, you need to convert your `array` string from a `String` to a `List` and then pass it to the adapter.

```
// I assume, the String is comma separated, which indicates the array.
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(array.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.extView);
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, arrayList);
lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Hope that helps!